# Tab characters not working properly in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use tab characters in Strings (\t) to indent my text, but it seems that Flutter displays all tab characters as single spaces.

For example, using Flutter's demo app, I want it to display  at the center of the screen this string:

'#1\tYou have pushed the button:\n#100\tYou have pushed the button'

and this is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFH0x.png

Here the \n is working properly but the \t is clearly not.

However, if I print out the message in the console, the \t works fine.

I've tried on both my Mac and my PC and always end up with the same result.

Any help?

Comment: It's really strange.
I couldn't do accurate tests, but it seems that \t works, but only in some cases.
Here you are an example:
https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b

'#\tYou have pushed the button:' //works well
'#1\tYou have pushed the button:' //not so good
'#23\tYou have pushed the button:' //awkward
'#123\tYou have pushed the button:' //works well

It seems that \t adds 3 white spaces and they can be filled up to 2 spaces.
If you fill them with 3 characters, \t will add 3 more characters.
Neither Expanded widget or string concatenation seems to help us.

Answer (score 1):

user rich text widget
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html
you can find the reference on the api docs

Answer (score -2):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Model model = Model();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              text: 'Hello\thello',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check out this example you will get the idea

Comment: I tried this but the tab character still doesn't seem to work. See this pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayOLi.png

Comment: can put some code so that we can see what's happening.

Comment: I used the exact code from the reply, except that I changed the text string to '#1\tYou have pushed the button:\n#100\tYou have pushed the button'.

Comment: If you do not show what you are coding, then i cannot tell you what is happening.

Comment: Agree with OP that this code does not work.